# Mysql: sorting rows of a subquery generated table not working working

Tags: mysql, configuration, subquery

I have a subquery (generated by an ORM for pagination purposes) that generates a table that is then sorted by the parent query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `distinctAlias`.`invoice_id` AS 'ids_invoice_id',
    `distinctAlias`.`invoice_id`
FROM
    (SELECT 
        `invoice`.`id` AS `invoice_id`
    FROM
        `invoice` `invoice`
    LEFT JOIN `user` `user` ON `user`.`id` = `invoice`.`user_id`) `distinctAlias`
ORDER BY `distinctAlias`.`invoice_id` DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 526734;
```

This subquery is giving wrong results (sort) because `` ORDER BY `distinctAlias`.`invoice_id` DESC `` did not apply to it in one of the development machines (windows). When I tried the same query with the **exact data and schema** on my Macbook, it's working as expected and the results are sorted by `invoice_id` correctly.

When I ran the subquery **(on both machines)** without the `` LEFT JOIN `user `` statement, as shown below, the results were sorted by `invoice_id` correctly and matches.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `distinctAlias`.`invoice_id` AS 'ids_invoice_id',
    `distinctAlias`.`invoice_id`
FROM
    (SELECT 
        `invoice`.`id` AS `invoice_id`
    FROM
        `invoice` `invoice`) `distinctAlias`
ORDER BY `distinctAlias`.`invoice_id` DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 526734;
```

I believe that this is related to Mysql configuration but I haven't found which configuration property that is causing the issue.

```
# Other default tuning values
# MySQL Server Instance Configuration File
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated by the MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard
#
#
# Installation Instructions
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# On Linux you can copy this file to /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options
# (@localstatedir@ for this installation) or to
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# On Windows you should keep this file in the installation directory 
# of your server (e.g. C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y). To
# make sure the server reads the config file use the startup option 
# "--defaults-file". 
#
# To run the server from the command line, execute this in a 
# command line shell, e.g.
# mysqld --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y\my.ini"
#
# To install the server as a Windows service manually, execute this in a 
# command line shell, e.g.
# mysqld --install MySQLXY --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y\my.ini"
#
# And then execute this in a command line shell to start the server, e.g.
# net start MySQLXY
#
#
# Guidelines for editing this file
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that the program supports.
# If you want to know the options a program supports, start the program
# with the "--help" option.
#
# More detailed information about the individual options can also be
# found in the manual.
#
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
#
#
# CLIENT SECTION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# The following options will be read by MySQL client applications.
# Note that only client applications shipped by MySQL are guaranteed
# to read this section. If you want your own MySQL client program to
# honor these values, you need to specify it as an option during the
# MySQL client library initialization.
#
[client]

# pipe=

# socket=MYSQL

port=3306

[mysql]
no-beep

# default-character-set=

# SERVER SECTION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# The following options will be read by the MySQL Server. Make sure that
# you have installed the server correctly (see above) so it reads this 
# file.
#
# server_type=3
[mysqld]

# The next three options are mutually exclusive to SERVER_PORT below.
# skip-networking
# enable-named-pipe
# shared-memory

# shared-memory-base-name=MYSQL

# The Pipe the MySQL Server will use
# socket=MYSQL

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306

# Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
# basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/"

# Path to the database root
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0\Data

# The default character set that will be used when a new schema or table is
# created and no character set is defined
# character-set-server=

# The default authentication plugin to be used when connecting to the server

# The default storage engine that will be used when create new tables when
default-storage-engine=INNODB

# Set the SQL mode to strict
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

# General and Slow logging.
log-output=FILE

general-log=0

general_log_file="SERVER-PC.log"

slow-query-log=1

slow_query_log_file="SERVER-PC-slow.log"

long_query_time=10

# Error Logging.
log-error="SERVER-PC.err"

# ***** Group Replication Related *****
# Specifies the base name to use for binary log files. With binary logging
# enabled, the server logs all statements that change data to the binary
# log, which is used for backup and replication.
log-bin="SERVER-PC-bin"

# ***** Group Replication Related *****
# Specifies the server ID. For servers that are used in a replication topology,
# you must specify a unique server ID for each replication server, in the
# range from 1 to 2^32 − 1. “Unique” means that each ID must be different
# from every other ID in use by any other source or replica.
server-id=1

# ***** Group Replication Related *****
# The host name or IP address of the replica to be reported to the source
# during replica registration. This value appears in the output of SHOW REPLICAS
# on the source server. Leave the value unset if you do not want the replica to
# register itself with the source.
# report_host=0.0

# NOTE: Modify this value after Server initialization won't take effect.
lower_case_table_names=1

# Secure File Priv.
secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads"

# The maximum amount of concurrent sessions the MySQL server will
# allow. One of these connections will be reserved for a user with
# SUPER privileges to allow the administrator to login even if the
# connection limit has been reached.
max_connections=151

# The number of open tables for all threads. Increasing this value
# increases the number of file descriptors that mysqld requires.
# Therefore you have to make sure to set the amount of open files
# allowed to at least 4096 in the variable "open-files-limit" in
# section [mysqld_safe]
table_open_cache=2000

# Maximum size for internal (in-memory) temporary tables. If a table
# grows larger than this value, it is automatically converted to disk
# based table This limitation is for a single table. There can be many
# of them.
tmp_table_size=9M

# How many threads we should keep in a cache for reuse. When a client
# disconnects, the client's threads are put in the cache if there aren't
# more than thread_cache_size threads from before.  This greatly reduces
# the amount of thread creations needed if you have a lot of new
# connections. (Normally this doesn't give a notable performance
# improvement if you have a good thread implementation.)
thread_cache_size=10

#*** MyISAM Specific options
# The maximum size of the temporary file MySQL is allowed to use while
# recreating the index (during REPAIR, ALTER TABLE or LOAD DATA INFILE.
# If the file-size would be bigger than this, the index will be created
# through the key cache (which is slower).
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G

# The size of the buffer that is allocated when sorting MyISAM indexes
# during a REPAIR TABLE or when creating indexes with CREATE INDEX
# or ALTER TABLE.
myisam_sort_buffer_size=9M

# Size of the Key Buffer, used to cache index blocks for MyISAM tables.
# Do not set it larger than 30% of your available memory, as some memory
# is also required by the OS to cache rows. Even if you're not using
# MyISAM tables, you should still set it to 8-64M as it will also be
# used for internal temporary disk tables.
key_buffer_size=8M

# Size of the buffer used for doing full table scans of MyISAM tables.
# Allocated per thread, if a full scan is needed.
read_buffer_size=18K

read_rnd_buffer_size=256K

#*** INNODB Specific options ***
# innodb_data_home_dir=

# Use this option if you have a MySQL server with InnoDB support enabled
# but you do not plan to use it. This will save memory and disk space
# and speed up some things.
# skip-innodb

# If set to 1, InnoDB will flush (fsync) the transaction logs to the
# disk at each commit, which offers full ACID behavior. If you are
# willing to compromise this safety, and you are running small
# transactions, you may set this to 0 or 2 to reduce disk I/O to the
# logs. Value 0 means that the log is only written to the log file and
# the log file flushed to disk approximately once per second. Value 2
# means the log is written to the log file at each commit, but the log
# file is only flushed to disk approximately once per second.
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

# The size of the buffer InnoDB uses for buffering log data. As soon as
# it is full, InnoDB will have to flush it to disk. As it is flushed
# once per second anyway, it does not make sense to have it very large
# (even with long transactions).
innodb_log_buffer_size=1M

# InnoDB, unlike MyISAM, uses a buffer pool to cache both indexes and
# row data. The bigger you set this the less disk I/O is needed to
# access data in tables. On a dedicated database server you may set this
# parameter up to 80% of the machine physical memory size. Do not set it
# too large, though, because competition of the physical memory may
# cause paging in the operating system.  Note that on 32bit systems you
# might be limited to 2-3.5G of user level memory per process, so do not
# set it too high.
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G

# Size of each log file in a log group. You should set the combined size
# of log files to about 25%-100% of your buffer pool size to avoid
# unneeded buffer pool flush activity on log file overwrite. However,
# note that a larger logfile size will increase the time needed for the
# recovery process.
innodb_log_file_size=768M

# Number of threads allowed inside the InnoDB kernel. The optimal value
# depends highly on the application, hardware as well as the OS
# scheduler properties. A too high value may lead to thread thrashing.
innodb_thread_concurrency=9

# The increment size (in MB) for extending the size of an auto-extend InnoDB system tablespace file when it becomes full.
innodb_autoextend_increment=64

# The number of regions that the InnoDB buffer pool is divided into.
# For systems with buffer pools in the multi-gigabyte range, dividing the buffer pool into separate instances can improve concurrency,
# by reducing contention as different threads read and write to cached pages.
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=3

# Determines the number of threads that can enter InnoDB concurrently.
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000

# Specifies how long in milliseconds (ms) a block inserted into the old sublist must stay there after its first access before
# it can be moved to the new sublist.
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000

# It specifies the maximum number of .ibd files that MySQL can keep open at one time. The minimum value is 10.
innodb_open_files=300

# When this variable is enabled, InnoDB updates statistics during metadata statements.
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0

# When innodb_file_per_table is enabled (the default in 5.6.6 and higher), InnoDB stores the data and indexes for each newly created table
# in a separate .ibd file, rather than in the system tablespace.
innodb_file_per_table=1

# Use the following list of values: 0 for crc32, 1 for strict_crc32, 2 for innodb, 3 for strict_innodb, 4 for none, 5 for strict_none.
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0

# The number of outstanding connection requests MySQL can have.
# This option is useful when the main MySQL thread gets many connection requests in a very short time.
# It then takes some time (although very little) for the main thread to check the connection and start a new thread.
# The back_log value indicates how many requests can be stacked during this short time before MySQL momentarily
# stops answering new requests.
# You need to increase this only if you expect a large number of connections in a short period of time.
back_log=80

# If this is set to a nonzero value, all tables are closed every flush_time seconds to free up resources and
# synchronize unflushed data to disk.
# This option is best used only on systems with minimal resources.
flush_time=0

# The minimum size of the buffer that is used for plain index scans, range index scans, and joins that do not use
# indexes and thus perform full table scans.
join_buffer_size=256K

# The maximum size of one packet or any generated or intermediate string, or any parameter sent by the
# mysql_stmt_send_long_data() C API function.
max_allowed_packet=4M

# If more than this many successive connection requests from a host are interrupted without a successful connection,
# the server blocks that host from performing further connections.
max_connect_errors=100

# Changes the number of file descriptors available to mysqld.
# You should try increasing the value of this option if mysqld gives you the error "Too many open files".
open_files_limit=4161

# If you see many sort_merge_passes per second in SHOW GLOBAL STATUS output, you can consider increasing the
# sort_buffer_size value to speed up ORDER BY or GROUP BY operations that cannot be improved with query optimization
# or improved indexing.
sort_buffer_size=256K

# The number of table definitions (from .frm files) that can be stored in the definition cache.
# If you use a large number of tables, you can create a large table definition cache to speed up opening of tables.
# The table definition cache takes less space and does not use file descriptors, unlike the normal table cache.
# The minimum and default values are both 400.
table_definition_cache=1400

# Specify the maximum size of a row-based binary log event, in bytes.
# Rows are grouped into events smaller than this size if possible. The value should be a multiple of 256.
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K

# If the value of this variable is greater than 0, a replica synchronizes its master.info file to disk.

# If the value of this variable is greater than 0, the MySQL server synchronizes its relay log to disk.
# (using fdatasync()) after every sync_relay_log writes to the relay log.
sync_relay_log=10000

# If the value of this variable is greater than 0, a replica synchronizes its relay-log.info file to disk.
# (using fdatasync()) after every sync_relay_log_info transactions.
sync_relay_log_info=10000

# Load mysql plugins at start."plugin_x ; plugin_y".
# plugin_load

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server X Protocol will listen on.
loose_mysqlx_port=33060



bind_address=127.0.0.1
mysqlx_bind_address=127.0.0.1
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size=128M
innodb_io_capacity=1000
innodb_log_files_in_group=4

innodb_ft_min_token_size=1
```

Comment: What's magical about `526734`?  Are you expecting the user to flip through 526734 pages???

Comment: Good point, the system has next and previous buttons. So, when the user opens a page (ex: via search), he/she has the ability to go one step back or forward.

Comment: Pagination via `OFFSET` is slow and can create surprises:  [_Pagination_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)

Answer (score 1):

While writing this question, I found the solution and I decided to post it so that may someone else find it useful.

The issue was that [max_heap_table_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_heap_table_size) is set to `16MB`, I changed it to `300MB` I got the correct results.

Comment: Best Practice indicates max_heap_table_size and tmp_table_size should always be the same in MySQL or MariaDB.

Comment: If `tmp_table_size` was 16MB, your change did not solve the problem.  Something else coincidentally "fixed" it.  If you have a reproducible test case, please file a bug report at bugs.mysql.com ; changing that setting should _not_ fix "wrong data".